# Is correct to say "her hair is black by nature/in nature" to mean that she or her hair was born that way?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

When we want to say that a person's feature because that the way it is, do we say "**by nature**" or "**in nature**"?

For example, "**her hair is black by nature/in nature**" to mean that she or her hair was born that way, not because of being dyed?

Comment: [What's the name for people with black hair?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33969/whats-the-name-for-people-with-black-hair) : *brunette*.

Comment: Nitpick: "Is *it* correct to say ...".

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Her hair is naturally black.**

People of European descent who have fair hair as children often find it turns brown when they grow up, and women may bleach theirs to retain the blonde colour - hence the question "Is she a [natural blonde?"](https://www.insider.com/celebrities-who-are-naturally-blonde#emma-stone-may-be-famous-for-her-fiery-red-locks-but-shes-actually-a-natural-blonde-1)

Comment: "Naturally" is also used with other adjectives that describe hair, such as "straight" or ["curly"](https://youtu.be/HkXaSgrTXSg).

Comment: I'm not native English, but I think it's also common to say "Her natural hair color is black". Also, if you want to ask somebody about their hair color you usually say "What's your natural hair color?". Am i correct?

Comment: @IvoBeckers - Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 8):

> Her hair is black by nature.

is grammatical, but a native English speaker wouldn’t say what you mean that way—to the point that if one used that sentence, I would wonder if they were trying to say *something else* with that statement.

The phrase “by nature” is often used with personality traits and social behaviors, to indicate that someone’s behavior is their “natural inclination” and not something they are putting effort into. It can be positive or negative, e.g. “he is cruel by nature,” “she is kind by nature,” etc.

How that would work with black hair, I’m not really sure. But I’d wonder if we were discussing some kind of metaphorical “blackness” (“darkness”), meaning evil or something. Then again, “evil hair” is confusing. I would *probably* wind up concluding that the sentence *probably* meant what you wanted it to mean, but I wouldn’t feel confident in that understanding.

> Her hair is black in nature.

is worse—it’s still grammatical, but “in nature” refers to how animals are found in their natural environments as opposed to how they are found in homes (as pets) or zoos. It’s the same as “in the wild.” And I don’t know how that would apply to someone’s hair, and I wouldn’t know what this sentence meant.

In both cases, knowing that you are a new English speaker would actually *help* understanding. My confusion in these cases comes not because of the words themselves—they could easily have the meaning you want them to—but because of how they are usually used, and how a native English speaker would normally say what you mean. Using phrasing that is usually used in other contexts, and *avoiding* the phrasing that would normally be used for this, would make me think that you *don’t* mean that. But if I knew you were a new English speaker, then I would understand that you wouldn’t know the “usual” way to say things, and then I wouldn’t wonder why you didn’t use that and would not be confused.

Anyway, as Kate says, the way a native English speaker would indicate the color of someone’s undyed hair is to say the color is “natural” or “naturally” rather than “in nature” or “by nature.” So the correct way to say what you mean is

> Her hair is naturally black.

or

> Her black hair is natural.

Comment: "black in nature" could also potentially be misunderstood as metaphorical. It doesn't scan that way for hair, but e.g. "Her heart is black in nature" would to me mean roughly "she is evil"

Comment: @BThompson True! I almost went back and edited something in about black hearts.

Comment: "Her black hair is natural" *could* be taken to mean that it is not a wig.

Comment: I’d probably say “Her natural hair color is black.” (Or “She has natural black hair.)